# SQL Pivot - Multi-row multi-column

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have data that i need to pivot to a grid view. Its 2 rows to join into one row and then pivot into columns.

Below is the data setup. I've only included Jan to Apr but this will be running for all months and the year can change but it will always be 2 consecutive years.

```
Sample Data


CREATE TABLE #tmpData (
    [YEAR] INT,
    [AMOUNT] DECIMAL(12,2),
    [PAX]   INT,
    [PRODUCTID] INT,
    [MONTH] INT,
    [MONTHNAME] VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO #tmpData SELECT 2012    ,3309       ,10 ,1  ,1  ,'January'
INSERT INTO #tmpData SELECT 2013    ,3257.25    ,11 ,1  ,1  ,'January'
INSERT INTO #tmpData SELECT 2012    ,4351.2     ,21 ,1  ,2  ,'February'
INSERT INTO #tmpData SELECT 2013    ,3719.25    ,31 ,1  ,2  ,'February'
INSERT INTO #tmpData SELECT 2012    ,4687       ,11 ,1  ,3  ,'March'
INSERT INTO #tmpData SELECT 2013    ,4120.74    ,11 ,1  ,3  ,'March'
INSERT INTO #tmpData SELECT 2012    ,6123.1     ,21 ,1  ,4  ,'April'
INSERT INTO #tmpData SELECT 2013    ,5417.25    ,21 ,1  ,4  ,'April'

INSERT INTO #tmpData SELECT 2012    ,5416.5     ,10 ,3  ,1  ,'January'
INSERT INTO #tmpData SELECT 2013    ,6104.6     ,20 ,3  ,1  ,'January'
INSERT INTO #tmpData SELECT 2012    ,9748.16    ,30 ,3  ,2  ,'February'
INSERT INTO #tmpData SELECT 2013    ,10797.43   ,30 ,3  ,2  ,'February'
INSERT INTO #tmpData SELECT 2012    ,12706.32   ,30 ,3  ,3  ,'March'
INSERT INTO #tmpData SELECT 2013    ,13194.3    ,4  ,3  ,3  ,'March'
INSERT INTO #tmpData SELECT 2012    ,16429.03   ,33 ,3  ,4  ,'April'
INSERT INTO #tmpData SELECT 2013    ,14339.92   ,37 ,3  ,4  ,'April'

SELECT * FROM   #tmpData
DROP TABLE #tmpData
```

Desired Results

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpResults (
    [PRODUCTID]         INT,

    [2013_JAN_AMOUNT]   DECIMAL(12,2),
    [2013_JAN_AMOUNT_%] INT,
    [2013_JAN_PAX]      INT,
    [2013_JAN_PAX_%]    INT,

    [2013_FEB_AMOUNT]   DECIMAL(12,2),
    [2013_FEB_AMOUNT_%] INT,
    [2013_FEB_PAX]      INT,
    [2013_FEB_PAX_%]    INT,

    [2013_MAR_AMOUNT]   DECIMAL(12,2),
    [2013_MAR_AMOUNT_%] INT,
    [2013_MAR_PAX]      INT,
    [2013_MAR_PAX_%]    INT,

    [2013_APR_AMOUNT]   DECIMAL(12,2),
    [2013_APR_AMOUNT_%] INT,
    [2013_APR_PAX]      INT,
    [2013_APR_PAX_%]    INT     
)

INSERT INTO #tmpResults 
    SELECT  1, -- PRODUCTID
        --AMOUNT    CALC= (JAN2013-JAN2012)/JAN2012                         2013PAX CALC= (JAN2013-JAN2012)/JAN2012
         3257.25,   ROUND((SELECT ((3257.25-3309)/3309)*100),0),            11,     CONVERT(INT,ROUND(CONVERT(DECIMAL,11-10)/10*100,0))--JAN2013
        ,3719.25,   ROUND((SELECT ((3719.25-4351.2)/4351.2)*100),0),        31,     CONVERT(INT,ROUND(CONVERT(DECIMAL,31-21)/21*100,0)) --FEB2013
        ,4120.74,   ROUND((SELECT ((4120.74-4687)/4687)*100),0),            11,     CONVERT(INT,ROUND(CONVERT(DECIMAL,11-10)/10*100,0)) --MAR2013
        ,5417.25,   ROUND((SELECT ((5417.25-6123.1)/6123.1)*100),0),        21,     CONVERT(INT,ROUND(CONVERT(DECIMAL,11-10)/10*100,0)) --APR2013

INSERT INTO #tmpResults 
    SELECT  3, -- PRODUCTID
        --AMOUNT    CALC= (JAN2013-JAN2012)/JAN2012                         2013PAX CALC= (JAN2013-JAN2012)/JAN2012
         6104.6,    ROUND((SELECT ((6104.6-5416.5)/5416.5)*100),0),         20,     ROUND((SELECT ((20-10)/10)*100),2)  --JAN2013
        ,10797.43,  ROUND((SELECT ((10797.43-9748.16)/9748.16)*100),0),     30,     ROUND((SELECT ((30-30)/30)*100),2)  --FEB2013
        ,13194.3,   ROUND((SELECT ((13194.3-12706.32)/12706.32)*100),0),    4,      ROUND((SELECT ((4-30)/30)*100),2)   --MAR2013
        ,14339.92,  ROUND((SELECT ((14339.92-16429.03)/16429.03)*100),0),   37,     ROUND((SELECT ((37-33)/33)*100),2)  --APR2013



SELECT * FROM   #tmpResults
DROP TABLE #tmpResults
```

Here is the data @ SQLFiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e8ed1/7/1

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the result you will have to look at pivoting and unpivoting the data in your table and since you want to do this for any two years, you will have to look at applying dynamic SQL.

First, let's start with the initial query to get the data for the 2 years.  You need to join on your table twice to get the data for the current year and the previous year.  The query will be:

```
select t.amount,
  round((t.amount-c.amount)/c.amount*100, 0) AmtPercent,
  t.pax,
  round((t.pax-c.pax)/(c.pax*1.0)*100, 0) PaxPercent,
  t.productid,
  t.monthname,
  t.year
from tmpData t
inner join tmpData c
  on t.monthname = c.monthname
  and t.productid = c.productid
  and c.year = 2012
where t.year = 2013;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e8ed1/48). Once you have the data calculated, then I would suggest unpivoting the `amount`, `amtpercent`, `pax` and `paxpercent` columns. This will turn the multiple columns into multiple rows for each `productid` and `month`.  Your initial SQL Fiddle was using SQL Server 2012 so I am assuming you are using a version greater than 2005.  If so, then you can use CROSS APPLY with a VALUES clause to unpivot the data:

```
select d.productid, 
   cast(year as varchar(4)) + '_' + monthname + '_' + col as col,
   value
from
(
  select t.amount,
    round((t.amount-c.amount)/c.amount*100, 0) AmtPercent,
    t.pax,
    round((t.pax-c.pax)/(c.pax*1.0)*100, 0) PaxPercent,
    t.productid,
    t.monthname,
    t.year
 from tmpData t
 inner join tmpData c
    on t.monthname = c.monthname
    and t.productid = c.productid
    and c.year = 2012
  where t.year = 2013
) d
cross apply
(
  values
    ('Amount', amount),
    ('AmountPercent', amtPercent),
    ('Pax', Pax),
    ('PaxPercent', paxPercent)
) c (col, value);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e8ed1/49). This gives you a result:

```
| PRODUCTID |                         COL |    VALUE |
------------------------------------------------------
|         1 |         2013_January_Amount |  3257.25 |
|         1 |  2013_January_AmountPercent |       -2 |
|         1 |            2013_January_Pax |       11 |
|         1 |     2013_January_PaxPercent |       10 |
|         1 |        2013_February_Amount |  3719.25 |
|         1 | 2013_February_AmountPercent |      -15 |
|         1 |           2013_February_Pax |       31 |
|         1 |    2013_February_PaxPercent |       48 |
|         1 |           2013_March_Amount |  4120.74 |
```

Now that your data is is multiple rows, you can apply the PIVOT function to the values in `col`.  These values were computed by concatenating the original column names with the year and month. When you apply the PIVOT function, the query will be:

```
select productid, 
  [2013_January_Amount], [2013_January_AmountPercent],
  [2013_January_Pax], [2013_January_PaxPercent],
  [2013_February_Amount], [2013_February_AmountPercent],
  [2013_February_Pax], [2013_February_PaxPercent],
  [2013_March_Amount], [2013_March_AmountPercent],
  [2013_March_Pax], [2013_March_PaxPercent],
  [2013_April_Amount], [2013_April_AmountPercent],
  [2013_April_Pax], [2013_April_PaxPercent]
from 
(
  select d.productid, 
    cast(year as varchar(4)) + '_' + monthname + '_' + col as col,
    value
  from
  (
    select t.amount,
      round((t.amount-c.amount)/c.amount*100, 0) AmtPercent,
      t.pax,
      round((t.pax-c.pax)/(c.pax*1.0)*100, 0) PaxPercent,
      t.productid,
      t.monthname,
      t.year
    from tmpData t
    inner join tmpData c
      on t.monthname = c.monthname
      and t.productid = c.productid
      and c.year = 2012
    where t.year = 2013
  ) d
  cross apply
  (
    values
      ('Amount', amount),
      ('AmountPercent', amtPercent),
      ('Pax', Pax),
      ('PaxPercent', paxPercent)
  ) c (col, value)
) src
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for col in ([2013_January_Amount], [2013_January_AmountPercent],
              [2013_January_Pax], [2013_January_PaxPercent],
              [2013_February_Amount], [2013_February_AmountPercent],
              [2013_February_Pax], [2013_February_PaxPercent],
              [2013_March_Amount], [2013_March_AmountPercent],
              [2013_March_Pax], [2013_March_PaxPercent],
              [2013_April_Amount], [2013_April_AmountPercent],
              [2013_April_Pax], [2013_April_PaxPercent])
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e8ed1/46).  As you can see if you are reporting on all 12 months, then you have a lot of hard-coding of columns.  Also if you want to change the years you will have to adjust the query.  If you want this to adjust based on a parameter that you pass in, then you will need to use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @currentYear int = 2013,
    @previousYear int = 2012

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(cast(year as varchar(4)) + '_' + monthname + '_' + col) 
                    from
                    (
                      select year, monthname,
                        DATEPART(MM,monthname+' 01 2013') mth
                      from tmpData
                      where year = @currentYear
                    ) d
                    cross apply
                    (
                      select 'Amount', 1 union all
                      select 'AmountPercent', 2 union all
                      select 'Pax', 3 union all
                      select 'PaxPercent', 4
                    ) c (col, so)
                    group by year, monthname, col, so, mth
                    order by year, mth, so
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT productid,' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
              select d.productid, 
                cast(year as varchar(4)) + ''_'' + monthname + ''_'' + col as col,
                value
              from
              (
                select t.amount,
                  round((t.amount-c.amount)/c.amount*100, 0) AmtPercent,
                  t.pax,
                  round((t.pax-c.pax)/(c.pax*1.0)*100, 0) PaxPercent,
                  t.productid,
                  t.monthname,
                  t.year
                from tmpData t
                inner join tmpData c
                  on t.monthname = c.monthname
                  and t.productid = c.productid
                  and c.year = '+cast(@previousYear as varchar(4))+'
                where t.year = '+cast(@currentYear as varchar(4))+'
              ) d
              cross apply
              (
                values
                  (''Amount'', amount),
                  (''AmountPercent'', amtPercent),
                  (''Pax'', Pax),
                  (''PaxPercent'', paxPercent)
              ) c (col, value)
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for col in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e8ed1/47). These queries give a result:

```
| PRODUCTID | 2013_JANUARY_AMOUNT | 2013_JANUARY_AMOUNTPERCENT | 2013_JANUARY_PAX | 2013_JANUARY_PAXPERCENT | 2013_FEBRUARY_AMOUNT | 2013_FEBRUARY_AMOUNTPERCENT | 2013_FEBRUARY_PAX | 2013_FEBRUARY_PAXPERCENT | 2013_MARCH_AMOUNT | 2013_MARCH_AMOUNTPERCENT | 2013_MARCH_PAX | 2013_MARCH_PAXPERCENT | 2013_APRIL_AMOUNT | 2013_APRIL_AMOUNTPERCENT | 2013_APRIL_PAX | 2013_APRIL_PAXPERCENT |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|         1 |             3257.25 |                         -2 |               11 |                      10 |              3719.25 |                         -15 |                31 |                       48 |           4120.74 |                      -12 |             11 |                     0 |           5417.25 |                      -12 |             21 |                     0 |
|         3 |              6104.6 |                         13 |               20 |                     100 |             10797.43 |                          11 |                30 |                        0 |           13194.3 |                        4 |              4 |                   -87 |          14339.92 |                      -13 |             37 |                    12 |
```

Comment: Perfect. Dose exactly what I need. Thank you so much. Love the breakdown for each section in the none-dynamic code, really helped me to understand what you were doing. Great job.